# Is it possible to change subscribe status from Bounced to Active

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to change the subscriber status from Bounced to Active. I tried several ways to do that but no luck.

1. Manually i tried to change the status. Its like i changed the status from bounced to unsubscribe and then activated again. Subscriber is still in bounced status.
   Bounced>Unsubscribed>Activate>Bounced.
2. I tried with API as well.

It seems when subscriber has bounced status after multiple retries then SFMC marked that subscribed as bounced and will not allowed to reactivate it again.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? And was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a multi-Business Unit setup, with settings configured to unsubscribe from all BUs, and you trying to resubscribe the subscriber from child BU. You need to do this from the root BU instead.

Also, you can use this SSJS to change the status to Active for multiple subscribers at a time, based on records in a data extension:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
var subs = DataExtension.Init(”SubscribersToReactivate");
var data = subs.Rows.Retrieve();
var allSubs = List.Init("All Subscribers - 112233"); //Update with the correct List ID for All Subscribers
try {for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
var statusUpdate = allSubs.Subscribers.Update({EmailAddress: data[i].EmailAddress, SubscriberKey: data[i].SubscriberKey},"Active");} } 
catch (e) {action = "error";}
</script>
```

Comment: Do i need the Pair of emailadress and subscriberkey or is subscriberkey sufficient along with the subscriberstatus?

Comment: It's been a while since I last tested this, but to my knowledge it required both email and subkey @JohannesSchapdick

Comment: Could i instead use this [call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_subscriberUnsubscribe.htm)? `var subObj= Subscriber.Init("SubKey");
var status = subObj.Unsubscribe();`

Comment: Yes, that should be OK. The main reason for me building the above, was due to lack of equivalent "Subscribe" function.